# xpath display data from nodes at different levels

Tags: c#, xpath

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<bookstore>            
        <book > 
            <title>aaaa</title> 
            -<author > 
                <first-name>firts</first-name> 
                <last-name>last</last-name> 
            </author> 
            <price>8.23</price> 
            <otherbooks>
                    <book > 
                        <title>bbb</title>      
                        <price>18.23</price> 
                    </book>     
                    <book > 
                        <title>ccc</title>      
                        <price>11.22</price> 
                    </book>     
            </otherbooks>
        </book> 
</bookstore>
```

I would like to select all books at different levels and then display information about each one (author, title and price).  At the moment code would also display otherbooks  for first book. What would be the best way of displaying only required information. 
I need to use XPath.

```
xPathDoc = new XPathDocument(filePath);
xPathNavigator = xPathDoc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator xPathIterator = xPathNavigator.Select("/bookstore//book");
foreach (XPathNavigator navigator in xPathIterator)
{
     XPathNavigator clone = navigator.Clone();
     clone.MoveToFirstChild();

     Console.WriteLine(clone.Name + " : " + clone.Value);
     while (clone.MoveToNext())
     {
         Console.Write(clone.Name + " : " + clone.Value + " | ");
     }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "at different levels"? Your selector retrieves `<book />` elements at all levels below `<bookstore />`. Don't you want `book/otherbooks/book` to be selected?

Comment: I want all books to be selected but then I would like to display info about each single book at the moment first book also include <otherbooks> info and then <otherbooks> are displayed again on their own

Comment: So is your current solution broken, or do you want to improve it? I think your current selector should achieve what you describe.

Comment: Selecting all books is working ok. I have problem how to display information about each book when iterating with use of XPathNavigator. My solution is going too deep and is display <otherbooks> for the first book when it should only display  (author, title and price)

Comment: If you can think of a better way of doing it with use of XPath please let me know.

Comment: Well, I'd know a solution using XSLT, but I'm not familiar with C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to try Linq To Xml :

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml); //or XDocument.Load(filename)
var books = xDoc.Root.Elements("book")
            .Select(b => new
            {
                Author = b.Element("author").Element("first-name").Value + " " +
                            b.Element("author").Element("last-name").Value,
                Books = b.Descendants("book")
                            .Select(x => new 
                            {
                                Title = x.Element("title").Value,
                                Price = (decimal)x.Element("price"),
                            })
                            .Concat(new[] { new { Title = b.Element("title").Value, 
                                                Price = (decimal)b.Element("price") } 
                                        })
                            .ToList()

            })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: It looks great but I am trying to familiarise myself with Xpath. I will be looking at linq to xml latter. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The double slash (`//`) is specifying [all descendents](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathdescendant.php), not just the immediate one. How about

```
/bookstore/book
```

? That will get you the top level `book` only.

Comment: I would like to get all the books (code is working ok) and the iterate them and display (author, title and price) for each single one. At the moment I am also displaying <otherbooks> data for the first book. I would like to avoid that. But I can't see a better way of accessing book nodes by iterating with XPathNavigator clone